# Google BigQuery streaming - time to insert

Tags: json, ssis, google-bigquery

I am working with Google BigQuery for the first time on a client project and have created packages in SSIS to insert data into tables (an odd combination but one required by my client), using an SSIS plugin (CData).

I am looking to insert around 100k rows into a BigQuery table, however, when I look to do further update queries on this table, these cannot be performed because the data is still in the buffer.  How does one know how long this will take in BigQuery and are there ways to speed up the process?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter if the data is still in the buffer. If you query the table, the data in the buffer will be included too. Just one of the many awesome things about BigQuery.

https://cloud.google.com/blog/big-data/2017/06/life-of-a-bigquery-streaming-insert

> A record that arrives in the streaming buffer will remain there for
>   some minimum amount of time (minutes). During this period while the
>   record is buffered, it's possible that you may issue a query that will
>   reference the table. The Instant Availability Reader allows workers
>   from the query engine to read the buffered records prior to being
>   committed to managed storage.

Comment: Hi Graham, it is true that you can query and select the data from the table, however you cannot update it when in the buffer (as far as I am aware).  I am trying to solve an issue where data from a supplier is retrospectively changed., so I need to delete rows from the table and insert the newly corrected figures

Comment: I don't think that's true actually. I had experiences of querying tables immediately after doing streaming insert and sometimes I wasn't able to retrieve these data. Also, the link you reported is saying `it's possible for the streaming readers to be unable to service query requests that want to read records from the streaming buffer. In these cases you may observe that the buffered data does not contribute to the query's results.`

Answer (score 1):

> data is still in the buffer. How does one know how long this will take in BigQuery?

Streamed data is available for real-time analysis within a few seconds of the first streaming insertion into a table.
Data can take up to 90 minutes to become available for copy and export operations. See more in [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/streaming-data-into-bigquery#dataavailability)

Meantime, [have in mind](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-manipulation-language#known_issues) - Tables that have been written to recently via BigQuery Streaming (tabledata.insertall) cannot be modified using UPDATE or DELETE statements. So, as stated above  - `up to 90 minutes`

> are there ways to speed up the process?

The only way in your case is to use loading data instead of streaming data. As per how I understand your case - data is in MS SQL, so you can potentially make your SSIS package batch aware and load it batch by batch through [Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-csv)